Under what conditions is the arithmetic mean an upper bound for the quadratic mean?
As is well known, the arithmetic mean (AM) is less than or equal to the quadratic mean(QM), i.e.,
$$
\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n} \leq \sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}{n}}.
$$
In the Lower bound for the arithmetic mean based on quadratic mean, it is mentioned that $Q M \le \sqrt{n} AM$, and this bound is tight.
Can we obtain stronger upper bounds by adding more assumptions?
For example, if we assume that $0 \le x_i \le \sqrt{n} x_j$ for all $i,j \in [n]$, can it be proved that $\dfrac{x_1^2 + \dots +x_n^2}{n} \le C\left(\dfrac{x_1 + \dots +x_n}{n}\right)^2$ for some constant $C$ that is unrelated to $n$?
---------------------------------------------------------------
I have proved that the claim in the example does not hold. Assuming that $n$ is large enough, let $n-\sqrt{n}$ values be $1$ and $\sqrt{n}$ values be $\sqrt{n}$, then we have
\begin{align*}
& \dfrac{x_1^2 + \dots +x_n^2}{n} = \dfrac{n-\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}n}{n} = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}); \\
& \left(\dfrac{x_1 + \dots +x_n}{n}\right)^2 = \left( \dfrac{n-\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}}{n} \right)^2 = \mathcal{O}(1).
\end{align*}
Therefore we cannot find such $C$ in the example.
---------------------------------------------------------------
Is there no stronger upper bound than $Q M \le \sqrt{n} AM$, unless $x_i \le C x_j$?

What do you mean by ${n}?$ in usual notation, the only element of ${n}$ is $n.$

I guess it means $[n]$, i.e. 1,...,n

Yes, it's $[n]$. Thanks for pointing this mistake.

Welcome to MathematicsSE! Please use mathematical notation and demonstrate what you have tried so far.

Take $x_1=M, x_{i>1}=0$, then we have $M^2/n\le CM^2/n^2$ which will not hold for any $C$ independent of $n$.

It seems clear that you have convinced yourself there is no better constant bound $C$, without additional assumptions / restrictions.  It is however still unclear exactly what assumptions on $x_i$ would be considered "reasonable / admissible". The closest I can make out is that you want some constant $C$ s.t. $Q\leqslant CA$, given $\forall i, j \in [n], \;0\leqslant x_i \leqslant mx_j$, where $m$ could potentially be a function of $n$.  Here $A, Q$ denote the AM and QM respectively, and are obviously functions of $n$ and the $x_i$. The rest of this post is under this assumption.
Note if any $x_j=0$, then $0\leqslant x_i \leqslant mx_j=0$ forces everything to be zero, and the inequality is trivially done then.
Else, using homogeneity and symmetry, WLOG we may assume $x_i$ to be in ascending order and set $x_1=1$. Then $x_n=m, \;x_i\in [1, m]$.
Under these conditions we can use the Pólya-Szegö inequality (can try finding a better public reference or put down a simple proof if useful) which effectively provides a reversal for CS inequality, which is really what $Q\geqslant A$ is all about.  With $a_k=x_k, b_k=1$ in the linked article Theorem 1, we get
$$n\sum x_i^2 \leqslant \frac{(m+1)^2}{4m}\left(\sum x_i\right)^2$$
$$\implies Q^2 \leqslant \frac{(m+1)^2}{4m}A^2$$
This gives you $C=\dfrac{m+1}{2\sqrt{m}}$, independent of $n$, and dependent only on the upper bound $m$ allowed for $x_i/x_j$.  Does that help?
